# What do these Tor warnings imply?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, windows, circuit, client

The Following warnings have been observed during Tor operations.

```
[Warning] onion_skin_client_handshake failed.
[Warning] circuit_finish_handshake failed.*
[Warning] connection_edge_process_relay_cell (at origin) failed.*
```

What are these warnings trying to tell?

Comment: Same problem here while running Tor expert bundle after self testing verifies that OR and Dir ports are reachable from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `onion_skin_client_handshake` is defined in [`src/or/onion.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/onion.c#l538) and performs the final step of the handshake when creating a circuit. This [warning](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/circuitbuild.c#l1269) tells you that the handshake has failed.

The log message `circuit_finish_handshake` comes from [`command_process_created_cell()`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/command.c#l359). This function tries to find out if the Tor client was the initiator of a circuit. If yes, the key processing is finished and the circuit will be extended. In the case of the error message the finishing of the handshake failed and Tor will close the current circuit.

In the last case Tor receives a relay cell and decides what to do with it. When this error message appears Tor wants to send it to the origin, but failed. (see [`circuit_receive_relay_cell`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/relay.c#l169)). If I understand the source code correctly, the relay cell is later dropped.

If I understand it correctly Tor saw a more or less incorrect cell (think of a package) and handled it somehow. The message shows you that something happened and Tor cared about it.

Comment: Is that more likely an error, or more likely an attack?